# Mechanism for reaction between aluminium and iodine

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What should be a suitable mechanism for the reaction between aluminium and iodine, catalysed by water?

In my initial approaches, I had first thought of repeated attacks of the lone pairs of oxygen in water on aluminium, then formation of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ by losing $\ce{H+}$, then $\ce{H+}$ attacking $\ce{I2}$, and formation of $\ce{HI}$, and finally formation of $\ce{AlI3}$.

But actually $\ce{Al2I6}$ is formed, so how can I accommodate its formation in that?

Is anything wrong in the above suggested mechanism? If the actual mechanism is something else, please write it in your answer.

A Lewis dot structure of the mechanism would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your proposed mechanism, which you would notice if you actually wrote the equations out.

Comment: The biggest problem is of course, my initially thought mechanism does not give me $\ce{Al2I6}$ , and that is why I asked this question.

Comment: $\ce{Al2I6}$ is just the dimer of $\ce{AlI3}$; if you generate the latter in a reaction equation you can stop there (potentially add $\ce{2 AlI3 <=>> Al2I6}$ at the end)

Comment: How is this a homework question? Why is this put on hold even though I have literally explained my initial approach?

Comment: @Jan I don't see the reason this would just pop up in the end. Mechanisms usually incorporate the step of instability which leads up to dimerazation

Comment: @Rohinb97 In a nutshell, $\ce{AlI3}$’s aluminium is not coordinatively saturated (i.e. could take one more ligand). Iodine is happy to supply that missing saturation and the resulting structure is a double tetrahedron connected along a side with two iodine bridging between the two aluminiums.